# Extended Entity-Relationship Diagram: Do the sub classes have foreign keys or primary keys?

Tags: database-design, schema, erd, subtypes

Consider this example (they are disjoint, by the way):

[image]

There are two scenarios which I am  guessing:

1. While translating it to relational tables,
   the rows in PROGRAMMER are unique which do not exist in EMPLOYEE table and it has a PRIMARY KEY
2. They already exist in EMPLOYEE table and the PROGRAMMER has a foreign key which references it.

Which scenario is correct? or both are wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not an either / or situation. The answer for your particular system may exists as a combination of these two options. Let me explain.

If the only attribute in common between the Programmer, Engineer and Admin tables are the Emp# then I'd likely implement them as separate tables. Each would have Emp# as the primary key. I would not implement the Employee table at all since it added no additional value to the run-time system.

If the three sub-types had many columns in common, say Name, HireDate, Department .. HolidayBalance, ContactNumber etc., and only a few sub-type specific values (as you've annotated on your diagram) you could put all columns in Employee and make the inapplicable ones (e.g. a Programmer's EType) NULL. A view can be defined for each sub-type if excluding the NULLs becomes tedious.

Likely the truth lies somewhere between these two - there are enough specific attributes in each sub-type to warrant its own table, but enough common ones to justify an Employee table, too. In this case I'd make Emp# the primary key of Employee and also each sub-type would have the primary key of Emp#, too. Further I'd define Programmer.Emp# to be a foreign key referencing Employee.Emp#, and the same for the other sub-types. In this way uniqueness is maintained within each sub-type and so is integrity between the sub-type and super-type. In other words, I'd make a one-to-one relationship between Employee and each sub-type.

I would not implement a surrogate key in each of the sub-types (for example ProgrammerId) as it adds nothing that Emp# can't already achieve.

Note that it is difficult to declaratively ensure mutual exclusion between the sub-types. This will be enforced in the application or through triggers.